# Align two Labels to be inline in XAML

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm styling in Xamarin Forms. I have problem with align Vertical 2 label other size:

[image: like this]

This is my XAML code:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Label Text="03" FontSize="42" FontAttributes="Bold" Style="{StaticResource LabelNormal}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="End" />
        <Label Text="\20" Style="{StaticResource LabelNormal}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="End" />
    </StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Chưa xử lý" Style="{StaticResource LabelNormal}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
</StackLayout>
```

I want "30" and "/20" are straight on bottom. How I can do it?

---

**Resovled**

[image: Image resoved]

This is my simple solution. I added Margin-bottom is "-7" and it worked.

```
<Label Text="03" FontSize="42" FontAttributes="Bold" Style="{StaticResource LabelNormal}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Margin="0,0,0,-7" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your solution is working it might be not the best, please consider the next topics:

- Negative values in padding can introduce inconsistent side effects on different screens and platforms. It should be considered as a very dirty hack and should be avoided.
- Performance. It seems that you overused `StackLayout`. Try `Grid`, it will reduce the amount of UI elements to render and will increase the loading time.

Good luck!

Comment: Now I have other solution is better than at this topic: 
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/44192642/6833593](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44192642/6833593)

That's right. I think I'm overusing `stacklayout`. My layout is hard to style on Xamarin Forms. I'm trying avoid large controls. However, thanks you for reply and your recommend, so it's very helpful for me.  I'll remove some `stacklayout` in my project.